# How do I install Parse command Line tool on Mac

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to install the Parse Command Line tool but get the following response:

```
curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
Fetching latest version ...
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: parse.comparse-osx-1.2.0
```

I'm following Parse's guide and still no fix.

Thanks

Comment: Report a bug to them, they've screw up some redirections on their end.